# Show $G$ is isomorphic to the multiplicative group $\mathbb{R}^\times$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid x>0 \text{ and }x\neq 1 \}$ and define $*$ on $G$ by $a*b=a^{\ln b}$.
>
> Show $G$ is isomorphic to the multiplicative group $\mathbb{R}^{\times}$.

I need to show it is preserved under its operation; that is:

$$\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\phi(b), \text{ where }a,b\in G$$

So what I did was construct a mapping, call it $r:G\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^\times$ where $r(x)=\ln x$. Then $r(a*b)=r(a^{\ln b})=\ln(a^{\ln b})=\ln b*\ln a=r(a)r(b)$

Would that be all I need to show for the preserving part?

I guess I can show that $r$ is one to one and onto.

So its one to one since if we let $x_1,x_2\in G$ and the conditions in the set $G$ are followed then $r(x_1)=r(x_2) \implies \ln{x_1}=\ln{x_2} \implies e^{\ln{x_1}}=e^{\ln{x_2}} \implies x_1=x_2$.

And its onto since if we let $x=e^{y}$ then $r(e^y)=\ln(e^y)=y$. Thus $r$ is onto.

I guess now I can claim it's an isomorphism.

***edit***
For the onto part could i state $r$ is onto because the range of $r$ is the set of all real numbers as long as $x>0$ and $x\neq 1$ for any $x\in G$.

Comment: Perhaps it is worth showing that $r$ is well-defined, i.e. that $\ln(a)\in\Bbb{R}^{\times}$ for all $a\in G$. Conversely, for your argument that $r$ is onto, you could explain why $e^y\in G$ for all $y\in\Bbb{R}^{\times}$. Otherwise you proof seems fine.

Comment: @user60887: Have u finished this question by yourself. I just want to know that. Thanks.

Comment: I've finished this question already.